# Custom Post Type and Taxonomies, creating the corresponding template file and loop the data

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I am creating this custom post(which is some sort of image gallery). Well each custom post also have this taxonomy, which works as a category type/post type.

My question is, how do I create a custom template page, and in that loop the data, which corresponds to the taxonomy? What should the file be named?

**THE CUSTOM POST**

```
$gallery_labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Photo gallery', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Gallery', 'post type singular name'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''

);
$gallery_args = array(
    'labels' => $gallery_labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail')
);
register_post_type('gallery', $gallery_args);
```

**REGISTER TAXONOMIE**

```
add_action( 'init', 'gallery_taxonomies', 0);

function gallery_taxonomies(){
    register_taxonomy(
        'phototype',
        'gallery',
        array(
            'hierarchical'=> true,
            'label' => 'Photo Types',
            'singular_label' => 'Photo Type',
            'rewrite' => true
        )
    );
}
```

Lets say I have these taxonomies

```
name  descripton  slug
A         ...      a
B         ...      b
C         ...      c
```

and then my custom post which uses the taxonomies (category style)

```
thumnail    title      phototype
1.png       one a          a
2.png       two a          a
3.png       one b          b
4.png       one c          c
5.png       two c          c
```

so if I go to the page

*myurl.com/phototype=a*
it should show

- one a
- two a

Comment: You should call your post type `gallery`. That name is used internally by Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for the little tip, just called it `mygallery` instead.

Comment: Your talking about taxonomy archive pages?

Comment: Hi Tom, I don't know what a taxonomy archive page is, but I am asking to get all the "custom post" corresponding to the selected garegory(taxonomy). But I actually believe that 'taxonomy archive pages' is what I am searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer,

since I am registering my taxonomy as `phototype` I simply have to create a file named `taxonomy-phototype.php` and inside that I will get the data by looping like I normally would in wordpress

```
<?php if (have_posts()): ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif ?>
```